# Folder path is dropped when redirecting with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I am redirecting all `non-www` to `www`.

It works fine for all links unless there is a link that contains a folder in our root directory, like `/us/` or `/uk/`.

This is my rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If I use tools like this one: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ it shows that the redirect is working fine:
http://example.com/uk/ redirects to http://www.example.com/uk/

But in reality it redirects to http://www.example.com/. I deleted every cache and varnish and also used tools like this: http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php and `cURL`.

The folder path is being dropped. http://example.com/uk/whatever becomes http://www.example.com/whatever

What else could it be?

I inserted my redirects also in a `.htaccess` file inside the /uk/ folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any other rewriterules ?

Comment: @Starkeen no, no other rewrite rules. is it possible that the htaccess from /uk/ folder is disregarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I inserted my redirects also in a .htaccess file inside the /uk/
>   folder.

You can not do that. It just gives the wrong result you get.

Use yours or this htaccess at root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this rewrite rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .? http://www.%yoursite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```